# Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error while connecting to mosquitto Mqtt through Mosquitto_pub and nodeJS only when configuring SSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, ubuntu-18.04, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto 2.0.7 version in ubuntu 18.0 i am able to connect without ssl configuration but i am getting `"Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error"` when i am configuring mosquitto with SSL (self-signed) configuration.
For SSL configuration i have created a local config file inside conf.d folder and configured as below

mosquitto_local.conf

```
listener 8883
#port 1883
#new
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt.key
#allow_anonymous true
#tlv_version tlsv1.2
```

Normal configuration file is like below.

Mosquitto.conf

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example
    pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
    persistence true
    persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
    log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
    include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
    max_inflight_messages 0
    max_queued_messages 0
```

Note1: With same configuration i am able to connect in other VM where mosquitto version is 1.4.0. I am  not able to figure it out weather it is mosquitto issue or some other issue. Even SSL certificates are also working fine when i am using them for other SSL configuration like mongodb.

Note2:Surprisingly i am able to download old version of 1.4.0 with command `sudo apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients` in other VM where SSL is working fine. But in this VM i am able to download latest version of 2.0.7 and open SSL version is 1.1.1.

Please let me know the mistake i am doing...Many thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using mosquitto_sub to connect from terminal and 'mqtt' library in nodejs and trying to connect like below

```
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 8883 --cert {path to cert} --key {path to key}  -t testtopic -m "hi"
```

Comment: Please check the version numbers in your question; latest release of Mosquitto is 2.0.7 so 2.7.0 looks like a typo, and I'm guessing by 14.0 you mean 1.4.0?. You also appear to have a typo in your `mosquitto_local.conf` file; the option is "listener" not "listner"; if that is not the issue then posting the Mosquitto log along with information on what you are using to test the connection (`mosquitto_sub`?) would help with further diagnosis.

Comment: @Brits - Yes those are typos, thanks for your effort and yes i am using mosquitto_sub to connect.

Comment: It would help if you'd share how you are trying to connect. We only have one side of the information here.

Comment: Hi romkey- I am trying to connect like : mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 8883 --cert {path to cert} --key {path to key}  -t testtopic -m "hi"

Comment: @karthikbulusu try adding the '--insecure' flag to the `mosquitto_pub` call (if that does not help adding `--debug` would provide some more info; as would the Mosquitto logs).

Comment: Are there any other errors or info from the mosquitto log file?  What error does the mosquitto_pub command return, if any?